# Pod with default class PV takes 30min to upgrade waiting for disk attachment

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed a helm chart (statefulSet) with 1 pod and 2 containers, one of the containers has a PV (readwriteonce) attached. On upgrade, it takes 30 mins (7 failed tries) to go up again (so the service is down for 30mins)

Some context:

- The PV is using the default GKE class
- is a GKE regional with one node in each zone
- The pod stars again in the same node even if not enforced (so not node transfer that I can see)
- I had a similar issue in azure AKS, it also failed 7 times but much faster so downtime was minimal and node transfer was involved

Relevant sections of the yaml file:

```
volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /app/data
    name: prod-data
```

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: prod-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 500Gi
      storageClassName: standard
      volumeMode: Filesystem
```

The error msg:

```
Unable to mount volumes for pod "foo" timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "foo". list of unmounted volumes=[foo] list of unattached volumes [foo default-token-foo]
```

The additional context, this is what happens after triggering the StatefulSet upgrade:

Nothing changed yet

```
Name:          prod-data-prod-0
Namespace:     prod
StorageClass:  standard
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-16f49d12-f644-11e9-952a-4201ac100008
Labels:        app=prod
               release=prod
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      500Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    prod-0
Events:        <none>
```

Then first error

```
Unable to mount volumes for pod "prod-0_prod(89fb0cf5-0008-11ea-b349-4201ac100009)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "prod"/"prod-0". list of unmounted volumes=[prod-data]. list of unattached volumes=[prod-data default-token-4624v]
```

Still same describe

```
Name:          prod-data-prod-0
Namespace:     prod
StorageClass:  standard
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-16f49d12-f644-11e9-952a-4201ac100008
Labels:        app=prod
               release=prod
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      500Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    prod-0
Events:        <none>
```

After the 2nd failed mount this is the pod description

```
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       False
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  vlapi-prod-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  prod-data-prod-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-4624v:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-4624v
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
```

FailedMount nr 3
no change to pvc description
events as described by pod

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                   From                                             Message
  ----     ------       ----                  ----                                             -------
  Normal   Scheduled    8m44s                 default-scheduler                                Successfully assigned prod/prod-0 to gke-vlgke-a-default-pool-312c60b0-p8lb
  Warning  FailedMount  2m8s (x3 over 6m41s)  kubelet, gke-vlgke-a-default-pool-312c60b0-p8lb  Unable to mount volumes for pod "prod-0_prod(89fb0cf5-0008-11ea-b349-4201ac100009)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "prod"/"prod-0". list of unmounted volumes=[prod-data]. list of unattached volumes=[prod-data default-token-4624v]
```

Warning  FailedMount  48s (x4 over 7m38s)
Warning  FailedMount  13s (x5 over 9m17s)

```
Name:              pvc-16f49d12-f644-11e9-952a-4201ac100008
Labels:            failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=europe-west1
                   failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=europe-west1-d
Annotations:       kubernetes.io/createdby: gce-pd-dynamic-provisioner
                   pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
                   pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:      standard
Status:            Bound
Claim:             prod/prod-data-prod-0
Reclaim Policy:    Retain
Access Modes:      RWO
VolumeMode:        Filesystem
Capacity:          500Gi
Node Affinity:     
  Required Terms:  
    Term 0:        failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone in [europe-west1-d]
                   failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region in [europe-west1]
Message:           
Source:
    Type:       GCEPersistentDisk (a Persistent Disk resource in Google Compute Engine)
    PDName:     gke-vlgke-a-0d42343f-d-pvc-16f49d12-f644-11e9-952a-4201ac100008
    FSType:     ext4
    Partition:  0
    ReadOnly:   false
```

FailedMount  47s (x6 over 12m)
FailedMount  11s (x7 over 13m)
FailedMount  33s (x8 over 16m)
FailedMount  9s (x9 over 18m)
FailedMount  0s (x10 over 20m)
~2m between FailedMount timeouts

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                  From                                             Message
  ----     ------       ----                 ----                                             -------
  Normal   Scheduled    24m                  default-scheduler                                Successfully assigned prod/prod-0 to gke-vlgke-a-default-pool-312c60b0-p8lb
  Warning  FailedMount  2m4s (x10 over 22m)  kubelet, gke-vlgke-a-default-pool-312c60b0-p8lb  Unable to mount volumes for pod "prod-0_prod(89fb0cf5-0008-11ea-b349-4201ac100009)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "prod"/"prod-0". list of unmounted volumes=[prod-data]. list of unattached volumes=[prod-data default-token-4624v]
  Normal   Pulling      11s                  kubelet, gke-gke-default-pool-312c60b0-p8lb  Pulling image "gcr.io/foo-251818/`foo:2019-11-05"
```

11th try to mount worked
no change I could catch on the PVC description

Comment: what are you upgrading? the statefulset? the node? the cluster version? What is the state of the PVC and PV during this process?

Comment: the statefulset is getting upgraded (ie: new image).
What do you mean by PVC state? when the statefulset is up, is mounted as expected, when the satefulset finish fetching the new image and try to mount the PVC I get the error in the post.

Comment: After you trigger the upgrade, check the pvc (kubectl get, kubectl describe)

Comment: @PatrickW I added more info to the question with the whole error process. Thanks!

Comment: The problem occurs with a volume "foo" initially , can you add the configuration of the foo is it persistentVolumeClaim?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that your pod has its spec.securityContext.runAsUser and spec.securityContext.fsGroup different than 0 (non root) and k8s would try to change file access for all files on the volume which takes some time.
Try setting them in your pod definition to

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
    fsGroup: 0
```

Other possibility might include mismatch of attributes (Access modes, capacity) between PVC and PV. Also, raising multiple pods with RWO PVCs, might create contention if you have a single PV of that kind defined.